# Content add-in dimensions change between computers

Tags: excel, office-js

To my knowledge, the maximum width of a content add-in is 10.42" in Excel. When my co-worker saves a file containing our content add-in with a width of less than 10.42", it shows up on my computer with a width greater than 11". This is proving to be problematic when trying to use CSS media queries. Is there a known reason why this would be happening and how we can prevent it?

We're both using the latest Excel for PC - Version 1708